# How can I refer a column of a Datatable by range and not by header name in C#

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, range

I have passed the information of an excel file into a datatable. 
I have to select only a part of the columns to take action. But four of the columns have the same header name so I cant refer to them by the header name.

**Ex. Data|Name|Service|extra|extra|extra|extra.**

I cant change the headers name because the excel file is a report generated automatically from a program. Till now for other functions i was selecting the columns like this:

```
DataTable dt = xls.ReadExcel(file);
dt = dt.SelectColumns(false, "Date", "Transaction ID", "Service ID", "Service",);
```

The SelectColumns method is:

```
public static DataTable SelectColumns(this DataTable dt, bool distinct, params string[] filters)
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            DataTable newdt = dv.ToTable(distinct, filters);
            return newdt;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your extension method to accept integers and filter out the columns that are not specified. You must iterate the collection "right to left", because it changes while iterating. This also means that you should enter the `params` in the correct order (from left to right, meaning smallest first) to ensure correct filtering. Other way would be to order the `params` collection within the extension method.
Also remember that the columns use a zero-based index, so the first column is 0, not 1.

This worked with quick tests.

```
public static DataTable SelectColumns(this DataTable dt, params int[] filters)
{ 
    for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        DataColumn c = dt.Columns[i];
        if (!filters.Contains(c.Ordinal))
        {
            dt.Columns.Remove(c);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```